# Access Apple Remote Desktop from Windows

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I'm looking for a way to connect to my Apple Remote Desktop at work from my Windows 7 PC here at home.

I already did it with VNC but I can't remember how the hell I did it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remotely administer Mac OS X Snow Leopard from Windows desktop?](http://superuser.com/questions/53348/how-do-i-remotely-administer-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-from-windows-desktop)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did:

Open "system preferences"

Click on "sharing"

Tick the box beside "screen sharing"

click "computer settings" to configure a VNC password